# Having problems clicking an element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a program which will trade stocks for me in the future. I have run into some problems after Logging In, typing the symbols of the stock, and now I need to click in some kind of way to be able to go on and buy the stock. I'm pretty confident that i know how to make a click with selenium but this tricks me out. I will give away the full code if anyone wants to try the program themself, just change the path to the browser! The account is fake, so don't worry.

Code:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 import time

 browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/larskvist/downloads/chromedriver')
 browser.get('https://www.forex.com/en-uk/account-login/')

 username_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Username')
 username_elem.send_keys('kebababdulaziz@gmail.com')

 password_elem = browser.find_element_by_name('Password')
 password_elem.send_keys('KEbababdulaziz')
 password_elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

 time.sleep(5)

 search_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.market-search__search-input")))
search_elem.click()
search_elem.send_keys('FB')

time.sleep(2)

search_click_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//app-market-table[@class='search-results-element ng- 
star-inserted']//div[@class='price--buy clickable-price arrows-flashing']")))
search_click_elem.click
```

The IMG shows what i want to click, when clicked manually a pop up buy option appears.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Selenium is **definitively NOT the way to go**. Use the [forex.com api](https://www.forex.com/en-us/trading-platforms/more-services/api-trading/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `webdriver` click is not working.

Induce `JS executor` to click on .

```
search_click_elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//app-market-table[@class='search-results-element ng-star-inserted']//div[@class='price--buy clickable-price arrows-flashing']")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_click_elem)
```

Browser snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, felt like i had tried everything with the Webdriver click. I Will take a look at the JS executor.Thanks again, love the effort!